# Calling function from a string in jquery but the parameter passed doesn't appear properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am creating an HTML element in a variable as a string and calling a function on its click. The issue is that when I am trying to pass an object to the function as a parameter, it is not being sent properly. When the function is called, I am simply consoling the object passed and it is logging [object Object], so its not accessible as an object. What am i doing wrong?

```
fnCreateElement: function(obj) {
        let mainObj = obj

        console.log('JSON received ----', obj)
        let el = '<span class="field-actions d-block">' +
            '<i  id="edit" class="fa fa-pencil pr-3 pointer" onclick="openModal(\'' + obj + '\')" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
            '<i class="fa fa-times pointer" aria-hidden="true" onclick="removeElement(\'' + obj.id + '\')"></i>' +
            '</span>';
```

The first console is printing the object properly in the fnCreateElement function but when the openModal function is called, it is causing the issue.

```
openModal = (obj) =>{
       console.log(obj) // output ---> [object Object]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to JSON.stringify() the object?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior.  If you want to display the object as a string in the console, then use [stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Objects are printed as JSON in the console, not just string.

Comment: Note that this won't work because of the mis-matching quotes in the resulting JSON. You'll need to escape them manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially parse the object to JSON before concatenating it, but this is creating more problems than it solves for two reasons. Firstly you'll have to work around the mismatched quotes in the resulting JSON by escaping them, and secondly you'll then need to parse the JSON again in the function you call.

A much better approach is to apply the object to a `data` attribute on a common parent element and then read it back out via delegated event handlers.

Also note that you are creating `id` attributes in the HTML you dynamically create. This can lead to duplicates if the function is called multiple times. To avoid this use `class` attributes on the elements instead.

With all that said, try this:

```js
let obj = {
  id: 'abc123',
  foo: 'bar'
}

// in the logic which creates the elements:
let $newContent = $('<span class="field-actions d-block">' +
  '<i class="fa fa-pencil pr-3 pointer edit" aria-hidden="true">Edit</i> ' +
  '<i class="fa fa-times pointer remove" aria-hidden="true">Delete</i></span>').appendTo('#container');

$newContent.filter('.field-actions').data('obj', obj);

// delegated event handlers somewhere else in your logic:
$('#container').on('click', '.edit', function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('.field-actions').data('obj'));
}).on('click', '.remove', function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('.field-actions').data('obj').id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing your JSON object to the `openModal` function as a string by quoting it. Removing the quotes should do the trick

```
onclick="openModal(' + obj + ')"
```

Comment: I did do that at first but it returns an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` at index.html:1. When I open the error, it shows a blank index.html file with just one line -> builder.openModal([object Object])

Comment: Ah yes it won’t work unless `obj` is available at time of click - I’ll have a think